# App store access when you already have an Enterprise Developer account?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, enterprise

My company has been an `Apple Enterprise developer` for a number of years.  We've built a handful of apps that are used by the company's employees, and we distribute them using a system called AirWatch.  That's worked fine for us so far.

Now we want to also offer apps on the `Apple App Store` for the general consumer to be able to make use of.  I have, of course, been unable to publish to the app store using our Enterprise account.  That I understand, as the comparison matrix of account types clearly states an Enterprise Account can't distribute on the app store.

What I don't understand is why I am also unable to sign up for a new Developer account as an Organization.  Apple rejected our application citing our existing developer account.

The key phrase in the rejection notice is this:

> We’ve withdrawn this enrollment because MY COMPANY NAME is already a member of the Apple Developer Program. Companies may hold only one membership in the Apple Developer Program.

Is that it?  We chose Enterprise first, and we're stuck?  Is there truly no way to offer apps to your own employees and then allow customers to access a different application as well?  That seems rather short sighted.  Surely the big banks get around this somehow.

We've asked Apple, but so far have not received any answers.  This can't be as uncommon as it looks when I have searched Google for answers.

Here's the complete rejection notice:

> Hello XXXXXXXXX,
>
> My name is Kelsey with Apple Developer Program Support. I am
>   contacting you regarding enrollment ID: XXXXXXXXXXX.
>
> We’ve withdrawn this enrollment because MY COMPANY NAME
>   is already a member of the Apple Developer Program. Companies may
>   hold only one membership in the Apple Developer Program.   Please
>   contact the team agent of your company's existing membership to be
>   added to the development team. If you do not know who the team agent
>   is, please provide your contact information. I will forward it to him
>   or her at your request.
>
> If you have any further questions, feel free to respond to this email
>   and I’d be happy to assist.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Kelsey
>   Apple Inc

I suppose it is possible that she is really saying that we already have an account in the regular Developer Program, and she is not referencing our Enterprise Program account at all.

Comment: Is the same Apple ID being used for both MY COMPANY NAME and the Enterprise Dev account?

Comment: Well, that's part of the issue.  If I try to use the same Apple ID, it tells me that I can't enroll in iTunes Connect.  When we try to use a different Apple ID (that's not part of the Enterprise team), our rejection notice told us that we are "already a member" of the Apple Developer program. It seems we can't use a new one, can't use the existing one.

Comment: That's very strange.  The only times I've seen similar issues to yours is when the same Apple ID is used for both.  Is it possible that the non-enterprise Apple ID is part of the team included in the enterprise account?

Comment: No, the ID we attempted to use for the regular Developer account was a brand new Apple ID.  Apple complained that it was the same legal entity as the enterprise account, with the same D-U-N-S number.

Comment: At this point, I'd say working with Apple directly is your only chance to get this resolved.